# No podspec found for `React-fishhook`

Tags: ios, react-native

When I upgrade react-native version 0.60.4 to 0.60.5, I find this error message after I try to `pod install` my iOS project. And I can not find any file under `node_models/react-native/Libraries/React-fishhook`, how should install it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to remove the pod from your Podfile as it is no longer needed.

Delete this line:

```
pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
```

See: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.60.4&to=0.60.5